# wxPython: How to make sizer fill its parent entirely

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a problem where `BoxSizer` doesn't fill its parent.

[image: Problem screenshot]

In the above screenshot I mean the sizer containing yellow and purple panels. I want this sizer and the panels to fill the entire panel in *Main* tab.

The only way I found to accomplish this is to `SetMinSize()` on the sizer to some big value. I can't set it to panel's actual size because `GetSize()` on the panel returns very small and definitely not real values.

Here's the relevant code:

```py
import wx


class App(wx.Frame):
    """Main app window wrapping around everything else.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        super(App, self).__init__(None, title='TSP Visual', size=(1200, 900))
        self.init_ui()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

    def init_ui(self):
        # Menubar
        menu_bar = wx.MenuBar()
        file_menu = wx.Menu()
        exit_mi = file_menu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, 'Exit', 'Exit application')
        menu_bar.Append(file_menu, 'File')
        self.SetMenuBar(menu_bar)
        # Main layout
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        # Title
        title = wx.StaticText(panel, label='No instance loaded')
        title_font = wx.Font(wx.FontInfo(18))
        title.SetFont(title_font)
        title.SetMinSize(title.GetTextExtent(title.Label))
        sizer.Add(title, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 10)
        # Tabs
        notebook = wx.Notebook(panel)
        main_tab = MainTab(notebook)
        stats_tab = StatsTab(notebook)
        notebook.AddPage(main_tab, 'Main')
        notebook.AddPage(stats_tab, 'Stats')
        sizer.Add(notebook, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT | wx.BOTTOM, 10)

        panel.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
        # Event bindings
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, lambda e: self.Close(), exit_mi)


class MainTab(wx.Panel):
    """Main tab of the app, solver controls and tsp view.
    """

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MainTab, self).__init__(parent)
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        # Panel sizer
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        # Solver controls and TSP view
        controls = SolverControls(self)
        controls.SetBackgroundColour('yellow')
        tsp_view = TSPView(self)
        tsp_view.SetBackgroundColour('purple')
        sizer.Add(controls, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(tsp_view, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)


class StatsTab(wx.Panel):
    """Second tab, graphs and statistics
    """

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(StatsTab, self).__init__(parent)
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        pass


class TSPView(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(TSPView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.SetBackgroundColour('white')


class SolverControls(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(SolverControls, self).__init__(parent)
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()
        text = wx.StaticText(self, label='Test text')
        sizer.Add(text, (0, 0), (1, 1), wx.ALL, 5)
        button1 = wx.Button(self, label='Button 1')
        sizer.Add(button1, (1, 0), (1, 1), wx.ALL, 5)
        button2 = wx.Button(self, label='Button 2')
        sizer.Add(button2, (2, 0), (1, 1), wx.ALL, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    App()
    app.MainLoop()
```

EDIT:
I've changed my code sample so it's self contained and runnable.

Comment: try to call `Layout()` on the outmost container.

Comment: @Igor I already tried calling `Layout()` in every place imaginable and unfortunately it doesn't help.

Comment: you should call it after `SetSizerAndFit()`.

Comment: Your code sample is impressively incomplete

Comment: @RolfofSaxony What do you mean? It misses 3 lines where I initialize wx and also source of `SolverControl` and `TSPView` but those are just panels. Right one is literally empty (looks exactly as as `StatsTab`) and left one has text and two buttons but you can think of it as empty because removing this text and buttons changes nothing.

Comment: @sajran Can anyone copy and paste your code sample and run it? No! If there is an issue with its execution, people have to be able to execute it to see if they can find a resolution. Your code sample is incomplete and therefore people have to guess what the missing bits are. It's been viewed 26 times (at this point) and only 2 people have been good enough to guess at the issue, everyone else has moved on to other questions.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony I guess you are right, I've updated my code sample. I really thought my issue is trivial to anyone more knowledgeable in this technology and running this code wouldn't be needed. I'm grateful for your help, however I think your comments could be more helpful and less offensive.

Comment: @sajran If you consider my comments offensive rather than helpful, in pointing out how your question could be improved and made easier to answer, feel free to report this matter to the administrators at StackOverflow. I personally don't see it that way but I'm perfectly happy to accept criticism.

Comment: @sajran Under linux wxpython 4.0.4 gtk2 & 4.0.1 gtk3 this code works. Changing all `self.SetSizerAndFit` calls to `self.SetSizer` it still works as expected. You may have to specify your OS and wxpython version, so that others with similar systems can test it.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony This made me think and I checked what will be the result of this code in Gnome session (I use i3wm as my daily driver). Turns out it works correctly under Gnome. Not really sure how to proceed with that, I didn't think window manager or desktop environment had anything to do with what's inside the windows.

Comment: @sajran Things can behave differently within the same desktop just by changing the `theme`, although it isn't usually a huge issue. If writing code for other people pick a common desktop and stick with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out the problem was somehow related to [i3wm](https://i3wm.org/) window manager. Since manually resizing the window fixes the problem I came up with a solution where I `SetSize()` of the window after `Show()`ing it. My `__init__()` method of `App` looks like this:

```py
def __init__(self):
    super(App, self).__init__(None, title='TSP Visual')
    self.init_ui()
    self.Show()
    self.SetSize(1200, 900)
    self.Centre()
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call `SetSizerAndFit()` in `MainTab.init_ui`: by calling this function, you change the size of `MainTab` to be just big enough to fit its contents. The yellow and purple panels should still get resized properly once you resize the parent window (if they don't, it means that there is another problem somewhere else, which I've missed), but to make it work from the beginning, just use `SetSizer()` instead.

Comment: It works after resizing parent window indeed but changing `SetSizerAndFit()` to `SetSizer()` doesn't make it work from the beginning.

Comment: Try changing all ot the `SetSizerAndFit` calls. It has unexpected side effects that are usually not wanted.